# Get dynamic id on jQuery toggle function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this Jquery function

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("tr").next().find("div").hide();
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();        
    $("#status_0").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("div").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

and I have dynamic id's that i'm generating this way :

```
<a id="status_@commandLine.lineRowId"><img src="~/fonts/details.png" style="width:40px; height:32px;" /></a>
```

I tried to add onclick event to my anchor but I have unstable behaviour...
Just a little precision, i'm generating my id's on td of a table

Comment: Use a common class on all the elements, or use a selector based on the element's parents, eg. `#container > div.something a`

Comment: Can you define what you mean by unstable behaviour? You should provide all relevant HTML markup including the table you mentioned.

Comment: @MasterYoda What I mean is that when i click for example in my first button (which was generated with a dynamic id) it's toggle 2 3 times arrow, when i click i an another button it toggle 2 3 divs (related with other buttons)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to use wild-card-like selectors to target elements.  If you know that all `<a>` elements will have a dynamically generated id with the syntax `#status_`, use the following selector to bind the click event.

```
var consistent_dynamic_string = 'status_';
$('a[id*="' + consistent_dynamic_string + '"]').each(function(anchor_index, anchor_element) {
    $(anchor_element).click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("div").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @LaalaDjelouah I had a typo in my code.  Your selector should be `$('a[id*="' + consistent_dynamic_string + '"]')`